# React/Typscript: typehint any doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, typescript-generics

I have a very simple react component named: `github.tsx`

In it, I have this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Github extends React.Component<{any, any}>{

  state = {
    user: []
  }

  getRepoUser = async () => {
    let res = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/example');
    this.setState({
      user: res.data
    })
  }

  componentDidMount () {
   this.getRepoUser()
  }

  render () {
    const { user } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{user.login}</h2>
        <p> repos: {user.public_repos} </p>
        <p>followers: {user.followers}</p>
        <img src={user.avatar_url} alt=""/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Github
```

I thought by adding `<{any, any}>` to the component, I would have no issues, but I see console errors like this:

```
backend.js:6 /home/example/tuts/components/github.tsx
./components/github.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /home/example/tuts/components/github.tsx(35,24)
      TS2339: Property 'avatar_url' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

I get the above error 4 times, for `user.login`, `user.public_repos`, `user.followers`, `user.avatar_url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a component, the first type you pass to `React.Component` is the props type, while the second one defines the state type:

```
interface IState {}

interface IProps {}

class Component extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
```

When you do this:

```
class Github extends React.Component<{any, any}>
```

You are only defining the component props type as an object that has 2 properties both called `any` which won't work.

Your component typing needs to be like this instead:

```
class Github extends React.Component<any, any>
```

Also the inferred type of `state.user` is an array since the initial state is:

```
state = {
  user: []
}
```

that's why you are getting the errors about `user.login`, `user.public_repos`...

You can type the state like this:

```
interface IState {
  user: User;
}

interface User {
  login: string;
  public_repos: string;
  followers: string;
  avatar_url: string;
}

class Github extends React.Component<any, IState> {
  public state = {
    user: {
      login: "",
      public_repos: "",
      followers: "",
      avatar_url: "",
    },
  };

  public getRepoUser = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get<User>("https://api.github.com/users/example");
    this.setState({
      user: res.data,
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting! But if `user` is supposed to hold an array, what do I declare in the typehint? do I just change the second hint from `any` to `array` as `<any, array>`?

Comment: as far as I understand from what you wanna do, `user` is an object, and not an array

Comment: Thanks bro, before I accept your answer, I just have one question if you don't mind. Why did you create `interface IState {
  user: User;
}` instead of using `interface User {...}` and passing it to component as `<any, User>` and what does `axios.get<User>` do? thanks very much

Comment: because your state is an object that has a property called `user` that contains the user infos-- if you do `<any, User>` then your state should contain the user infos directly ( `state = {login: .., followers: ..}` )..

Comment: `axios.get<User>` this is just for typing the `res.data`

Answer (score 1):

You are making a semantic mistake. While your program is syntactically valid, it does not mean what you appear to intend.

The critical point is that, in TypeScript, declarations have the form

```
<name> [: type]
```

That is to say that a name comes first and is required is always required and may be followed by a type annotation if desired.

Therefore, if I write,

```
type Props = {
    any
};
```

I am declaring a type with a *property* named `any`. The above is equivalent to

```
type Props = {
    any: any
};
```

Because I have no type annotation and no context whence to infer it.

Furthermore, I write,

```
type Props = {
    any,
    any
};
```

I have a declared a member named `any` twice, an error.

What you likely intended was to specify the type `any` for both the `Props` and `State` type parameters like so.

```
class Github extends React.Component<any, any> {

}
```

But you instead specified the type `{any, any}` for `Props`, and did not specify a type for `State`.

Comment: Thanks, what would I pass for the state if user is array?

Comment: `{user: UserType[]}`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons for that:

1. `React.Component` interface accepts two types, `React.Component<P, S>` where P is type for props and S is type for state. It can also accept a single type which would be just P. This is what is happening in your case, you are defining type P as object `{any, any}` (typescript should complain about it because you specify duplicate key). This means that you are not providing type for the State at all. which from the [DefinetelyTyped should be any](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3317a1c2cf540224a0d9630a281b3c7cfe99a3b0/types/react/index.d.ts).
2. you are explicitly defining `state` on the class, so typescript defers the type for it from the definition. `state.user` is an array so there is no `avatar_url` on this element;

To fix this you can try explicitly stating that `state` is any when defining

```
    state: any = {
        user: []
    }
```

Better solution would be to actually define a type or interface for the state and not use any. `any` should be avoided, especially in the code which you write for your application.

You can define user like type or interface:

```
type User = {
    name: string,
    avatar?: string
}
// or 
interface IUser {
    name: string,
    avatar?: string
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how should I define if `user` has multiple keys, like `name` `avatar`? Can I do `Interface User: {name: string, avatar: string}` and pass `User` like .. `<P, User}` ?

Answer (score 0):

"Typehint" in `React.Component<{any, any}>` has nothing to do with state type, this is props type you specified. Check out react component's declaration: `declare class React$Component<Props, State = void> { ...`

Comment: Also you mislead the compiler when you initialize state with an empty array, thus making it treat state's type as `any[]`

Comment: I wish you provided more info than that, I am now more confused than before. Can you give me a link where this is explained?

Comment: Well I meant state's type was calculated as `{user: any[]}`. You may provide it explicitly as guys above proposed. Also keep in mind that you might get runtime errors when you call those properties (login, followers etc.) on an empty array, so you should put some checks there.

Comment: In fact, better just initialize user with empty object `user: {}`, that should do the trick